# Using an ifelse loop with a date column in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am using a `for-loop` to go through a list of data frames. Inside the loop I filter each dataset (which include a date column) and then the output is used for calculations (including an `ifelse` loop). My problem is that sometime the output of the filter has no rows (empty dataset) and then it stopped the `for-loop` with the error

```
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

here is some code to reproduce the error message.

```
data1 <- data.frame(Date = as.Date("2016-01-01"), Filter1= 6)
data2 <- data.frame(Date = as.Date("2016-01-01"), Filter1= 3)
anomalies <- subset(data1, Filter1 <= 3) #won't work with the loop
anomalies <- subset(data2, Filter1 <= 3) #work with the loop

if(is.data.frame(anomalies) & nrow(anomalies)==0) {
        anomalies[1, ] <- 0
        } else{ 
        anomalies <- anomalies  
        }
```

data2 will work but if I run data1 I get

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

I tried to format the date before and inside the `ifelse` loop but no success. I am aware of several questions on `ifelse` and `date` on SO but none deals with empty data frames. Any help on how to fix (or an alternative) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide an example of the original task you are performing? I doubt you need a for loop, and this whole empty data.frame problem can simply be avoided.

Comment: You're trying to assign 0 to dataframe by this statement?
anomalies[1, ] <- 0

Comment: perhaps post a complete code sample of what you are trying to achieve so folks can propose even better ways to do it i.e. beyond the 'as.POSIXct.numeric(value)' problem.

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra, to answer your question. My original task is to use a for loop (another one; which is the core of our work) for each individual dataset we have. But now we want to automate our work and run this for loop for all our datasets. So instead of running individually each dataset, I thought using a for loop would be a good idea.

Comment: fyi, I can't post the code because it's confidential. So I can only reproduce the error.

Comment: You can simply construct some bogus data that reproduces your issue without giving away your data. A data.frame with random numbers for example. The solution will probably entail reading the separate datasets, merging them (e.g. using `rbind`), and then performing the operation on the entire dataset (e.g. using `dplyr`).

Comment: @Paul, Thanks you are actually giving me an idea I would like to try.

Comment: Good luck, and post your solution as an answer if you get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Paul Hismstra, I have a found a way to get around my problem by adding a row to each dataset (before my first `for-loop`) to make sure all my datasets will pass the `filter` step. By doing so, I don't have to (or try to) rely on this `ifelse` loop

```
if(is.data.frame(anomalies) & nrow(anomalies)==0) {
        anomalies[1, ] <- 0
        } else{ 
        anomalies <- anomalies  
        }
```

I did found a solution to my problem but not a solution on how to use `ifelse` loop with a date column.